# Failed to pass state to other router with useNavigate

Tags: reactjs

Hello i have a ecommerce react application and want to pass my state data from router "/cart" to "/success" after user finish the payment, to do that i use useNavigate in my cart route and in the success route i use useLocation to get the state, but after console.log the state is null. I have no clue to solve this problem, i need help Thanks.

This is the console log  :

```
hash: ""
key: "7e7cgplo"
pathname: "/success"
search: ""
state: null
```

I should be able to see my stipe payment data in the state(the api is working fine)

Cart.js

```
const Cart = () => {

    const cart = useSelector(state=>state.cart);
    const [ stripeToken, setStripeToken ] = useState(null);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
    const onToken = (token) => {
        setStripeToken(token);
    }

    console.log(stripeToken)

    useEffect(() => {
        const makeRequest = async () => {
            try{
                const response = await userMethod.post("/test", {
                    tokenId: stripeToken.id,
                    amount: 500,
                })
                navigate("/success", { data: response.data });
            } catch (err) {
            } 
        }
        stripeToken &&  makeRequest();
    }, [stripeToken, cart.total, navigate])



  return (
    <Container>
        <Navbar />
        <Wrapper>
            <Title>Your Bag</Title>
            <Top>
                <TopButton>Continue Shopping</TopButton>
                <TopTexts>
                    <TopText>Shooping Bag({cart.quantity})</TopText>
                    <TopText>Your Wishlist</TopText>
                </TopTexts>
                <TopButton type="filled">Checkout Now</TopButton>
            </Top>
            <Bottom>
                <Info>
                {cart.products.map((product) => (
                    <Product>
                        <ProductDetail>
                            <Image src={product.img} alt="google"></Image>
                            <Details>
                                <ProductName><b>Product:</b> {product.title}</ProductName>
                                <ProductId><b>ID:</b> {product._id}</ProductId>
                                {/* <ProductColor color="black" />
                                <ProductSize><b>Size:</b> XL</ProductSize> */}
                            </Details>
                        </ProductDetail>
                        <PriceDetail>
                            <ProductAmountContainer>
                                <AiOutlineMinus />
                                <ProductAmount>{product.quantity}</ProductAmount>
                                <GrAdd />
                            </ProductAmountContainer>
                            <ProductPrice>$ {product.price * product.quantity}</ProductPrice>
                        </PriceDetail>
                    </Product>
                        ))}
                    <Hr></Hr>
                </Info>
                <Summary>
                    <SummaryTitle>Order Summary</SummaryTitle>
                        <SummaryItem>
                            <SummaryItemText>Subtotal</SummaryItemText>
                            <SummaryItemPrice>$ {cart.total}</SummaryItemPrice>
                        </SummaryItem>
                        <SummaryItem>
                            <SummaryItemText>Estimated Shipping</SummaryItemText>
                            <SummaryItemPrice>$ 5</SummaryItemPrice>
                        </SummaryItem>
                        <SummaryItem>
                            <SummaryItemText>Shipping Discount</SummaryItemText>
                            <SummaryItemPrice>$ -6</SummaryItemPrice>
                        </SummaryItem>
                        <SummaryItem>
                            <SummaryItemText type="total">Total</SummaryItemText>
                            <SummaryItemPrice>$ {cart.total}</SummaryItemPrice>
                        </SummaryItem>
                        <StripeCheckout 
                            name="Kimia shop" 
                            image="https://d3o2e4jr3mxnm3.cloudfront.net/Mens-Jake-Guitar-Vintage-Crusher-Tee_68382_1_lg.png"
                            billingAddress
                            shippingAddress
                            description={`your total is $ ${cart.total}`}
                            amount={cart.total * 100}
                            token={onToken}
                            stripeKey={KEY}
                            >
                            <Button>Checkout Now</Button>
                        </StripeCheckout>
                </Summary>
            </Bottom>
        </Wrapper>
        <Footer />
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Cart
```

Success.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const Succes = () => {
  
  const location = useLocation();

  console.log(location)

  return (
    <div>Succes!!</div>
  )
}

export default Succes
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to redirect with `navigate("/success", { state: response.data })`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the issue is that you are passing the data as `data`, it should be `state` instead:

```js
navigate('/success', { state: response.data })
```